# custom file open with custom application only

Tags: vb.net, file

I am working on vb.net application where I wanted to create and read a file. File will have specific extension for ex. .abcb the way I want my application to work is:

1. can create a file with .abcd extension
2. should read .abcd files only(and also application created files only so altered extension shouldn't be working)
3. .abcd files should show some garbage data when open in any other application(ex. word, notepad any image viewer etc.)

Now my application does 1,2(partly) step, i.e. it creates a file and load data also, it reads .abcd files only(not the altered files)

but created file can be read by other software's also.I tried searching a lot but have not found anything and don't know where to start.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The file contains the same thing whether read by your app or some other app.  Windows is not going to change the contents depending on which app opens the file.  Its not your file, it belongs to the user.  If you dont want it to be read by other apps, use a binary serializer (unless it is predominately text) or encrypt it.

Comment: Besides what Plutonix already proposed, you could zip the file, then change the first 5 bytes of that file (set them to 0). That pattern is fixed, so you just need to change it back when opening the file. If the header is modified, compression sofwares will not recognize the format and will not open it.

Comment: thanks a lot Plutonix and Jimi I think I am going with encryption. so far I have encrypted and de-crypted files within application. only thing I have to do is when double click on file it should start different part in application. so my application default page is form 1's 1st tab to create project and save data and 2nd tab is to view data. so when double click on file should go to 2nd tab to show data. don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want other programs to be able to read the content of your file then your going to have to mask it in some way, which is usually done with encryption.

assuming your not too worried about the key being compromised, the easiest way to accomplish this would be to generate a key with something like [System.Security.Cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/walkthrough-encrypting-and-decrypting-strings) and use that key to encyrpt everything you send to the file and everything you read from it.

as for making your own file extension, you can make the extension of a file whatever you want when you make it:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create("/path/to/file/filename" & ".abcd")
```

the only thing that the extension does is tell the OS what progam to use when opening a file by default, which will probably be notepad since your making your own extension

Comment: thanks a lot doom87er. I am going with encryption. I have added line for key registry to open file with default program which is my application. only thing I have to do is when double click on file it should start different part in application. so my application default page is form 1's 1st tab to create project and save data and 2nd tab is to view data. so when double click on file should go to 2nd tab to show data. don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: thats a fairly complex issue and is also a separate topic, so I won't go into too much detail here. But, when the OS uses your program to open the file it'll supply the path to that file as an argument in the main method. From their you'll have to add a check for the file and what to do with it if you got it

Comment: Hi doom87er, Many thanks for your help! I think i found my answer here: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_crypt_file.html